# How to exclude a route from the firewall? (or avoid session cookie)

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have this firewall which includes anything that begins with /user or /admin.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/(user|admin)
```

But now I need to exclude `/user/profile/{user_id}`. Can this be done with a regex? For now, it's fine if it excludes anything that begins with /user/profile, if that's easier.

Is there any other mechanism provided by Symfony2 to exclude routes?

**EDIT**

I need to **totally exclude** said route to avoid sending the session cookie; allowing anonymous access with `access_control` is not enough. If you know a way to stop that cookie, it can be a solution too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but this regex should work:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/(user|admin)(?!/profile)
```

Comment: It worked, but I changed it to `^/(user(?!/profile)|admin)` and it also worked. Thanks